How to move a line (or arrow) in tikzpicture with coordinates
I wanted to move Line C so that it ranges from the end of line A to the End of line B in tikz (it should be parallel to A and B to show the lenght difference). How do I do that? I tried with coordinates but it didnt work really, it just made the arrow longer or shorter.
Sorry if the question is a bit simple, I havent been using Latex or tikz for long.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18, width=10cm}
\usepackage{float}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\section{test}
\begin{tikzpicture}

  \node (start) at (0,0) {A};
  \node (end) at (4,0) {$10m$};
  \draw[->] (start) -- (end);
\end{tikzpicture}
\newline

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (start) at (0,0) {B};
  \node (end) at (10,0) {$30m$};
  \draw[->] (start) -- (end);
\end{tikzpicture}
\newline

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (start) at (-2,0) {C};
  \node (end) at (8,0) {$20m$};
  \draw[->] (start) -- (end);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}```



Actually from the end of a to the end of b https://i.sstatic.net/0qW60uCY.png or should the line be parallel to the others and just show the length difference?

You might want to have a look at the siunitx package to typeset your units properly.

You could use a single TikZpicture:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18, width=10cm}
\usepackage{float}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\section{test}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}
  \node[anchor=east] (start) at (0,0) {A};
  \node[anchor=west] (end) at (4,0) {$10m$};
  \draw[->] (start) -- (end);
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[yshift=-1cm]
  \node[anchor=east] (start) at (0,0) {B};
  \node[anchor=west] (end) at (10,0) {$30m$};
  \draw[->] (start) -- (end);
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[yshift=-2cm]
    \node[anchor=east] (start) at (4,0) {C};
    \node[anchor=west] (end) at (10,0) {$20m$};
    \draw[->] (start) -- (end);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


